# At what altitude should I join overhead a fix when my legal MSA is lower than the holding altitude?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, south-africa

For example, if my MSA is 4600ft and the holding altitude is 6500ft, am I legally allowed to join overhead the fix at 4600ft, or do I need to join overhead the station at 6500ft?

[image: Example of plate]

Comment: Can you clarify what MSA means in South Africa?  In the US it is a sector altitude that will provide 1000' of obstacle clearance or 2000' in mountainous areas.  In this case it looks like there is a 4600' mountain west of the field, and an MSA of 4600'.  Zero clearance in other words.  Am I interpreting this correctly?  Because you really don't want to fly in IMC at 4600', in any sector...  (and it's 7300' to the East!)

Comment: @MichaelHall It sure looks like the SA protocol is that the MSA presented is the actual maximum terrain level for the sector and leaves it to the pilot to factor in obstacle clearance.  I tried hunting around for SA approach chart conventions but struck out.

Comment: @MichaelHall MSA in it's respective sector will give you 1500ft clearance over obstacles in South Africa.

Comment: @Skydemon, ok... but what does "46" mean on that thing that looks like a mountain 10nm West of the VOR?  Is the terrain actually 3100' so that you can fly over the top of it at 4600'?